# Python os.path.join incorrectly appending paths

Tags: python, python-os

The python `os` module seems to be incorrectly joining paths. To replicate, simply run the following code:

```
import os
p1 = "/1/2"
p2 = "/3/4"
print(os.path.join(p1,p2))
```

Which will print `"/3/4"`. Is this the expected behaviour? I would expect it to print `"/1/2/3/4"`

Comment: Since both paths start with `/`, they are by definition paths from the root - if you were to access one from the other or the other way around, you'd always get the absolute path from the root, so `os.join` is correct. Compare if  `p1 = "/1/2"` and `p2 = "3/4"`

Comment: @Grismar Ahh I see, I overlooked this because it's easy to forget a `/` somewhere in the code so I added a `/` to the start of the path for joining purposes, but this only made it worse! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That is by design](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os%20path%20join#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

If `3/4` should be a subdirectory of `/1/2`, omit the leading `/`:

```py
import os

p1 = "/1/2"
p2 = "3/4"
print(os.path.join(p1,p2))
```

As [Olvin Roght suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675058/python-os-path-join-incorrectly-appending-paths/70675074?noredirect=1#comment124940401_70675074), you can also remove leading slashes from `p2` using something like this:

```
p2 = p2.lstrip("/\\")
```

before trying to join if you cannot directly modify the string. This will remove `/` or `\` characters from the string.

Comment: You can also add `p2.lstrip("/\\")` in case if input can't be modified